# Как запускать аппликацию (андроид студио) по выходу из спящего режима?

Tags: android, android-studio

Всем привет
Если нужно чтобы аппликация (андроид студио) запускалась по выходу из спящего режима, или по завершению рестарта, или по завершению запуска мобильника или после разблокировки (и в случае если поставлен на пароль и в случае если только включен режим разблокировки путем касания экрана). Как бы вы это реализовали?Не ожидаю получить решение, а просто на уровне алгоритма и используемых инструментов и механизмов.
Спасибо
Леон

Answer (score 0):

Все варианты что вы хотите делать, делаются через BroadcastReceiver. Это такой один из мощных компонентов в Android который чаще всего декларируется в манифесте приложения, но не всегда.

например чтоб спящего режима используем action.ACTION_SCREEN_ON, а при загрузке системы используется action BOOT_COMPLETED,
но на него требуется разрешение `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>`

кончено есть куча хаков как делать иначе и без разрешений, но вам же интересен именно механизм, так что смотрите в сторону

> BroadcastReceiver

вот что долго не искать https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html